# Could I remove "reference to" from "being informed by reference to"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

[A Cambridge english Vocabulary](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/Images/84669-pet-vocabulary-list.pdf) says

> The vocabulary of English changes over time, with words being added and other words falling into disuse. In order to maintain its currency, the Preliminary and Preliminary for Schools Vocabulary List is updated on an annual basis, with the decision to add or remove words being `informed by reference to` the Cambridge Learner Corpus and English Profile Wordlists.

I've got the basic idea of this paragraph but I am being confused about this expression "being informed by reference to".

Why would the author express that way? Could I remove "reference to", and express as "informed by the Cambridge Learner Corpus and English Profile Wordlists"?

in another word, what is the difference between following 2 expressions?

expression_1:

informed by the Cambridge Learner Corpus and English Profile Wordlists

expression_2:

informed by reference to the Cambridge Learner Corpus and English Profile Wordlists

is "reference to" enhancing something?

Answer (score -1):

Yes: though unnecessary, it is perfectly valid to remove "reference to."

Comment: This answer is **very** brief and has no supporting details.  Can you provide a little more detail in your answer, or examples of usage that will help learners?